# Program only sees 1 input device

Tags: raspberry-pi, input, raspbian

I have a program ([advancemame](http://advancemame.sourceforge.net)) running on Raspian (Raspberry Pi) which like most programs gets its input from the keyboard. I'm using a program which implements `uinput` to convert GPIO pins HI/LOW readings to key presses ([pikeyd](https://github.com/mmoller2k/pikeyd)). I run `pikeyd` in the background from the terminal, which has a GPIO pin mapped to key 5. I set the corresponding GPIO to HI, it prints out "5" to the terminal.

However, when I run `advancemame`, it doesn't recognize the `uinput`. If I unplug the keyboard and reboot, then `advancemame` sees `uinput` and everything works. From what it looks like is the program will read the first input device, `input0` (keyboard). Is there a way to make `uinput` `input0`? That is, set the order of the input devices

```
$ ls /sys/class/input/
  event0  event1  event2  input0  input1  input2  mice  mouse0  mouse1

$ ls /sys/devices/virtual/input/input2/
  capabilities  event2  id  modalias  mouse1  name  phys  power  properties  subsystem  event  uniq
```

I'm not sure if there is a setting in `advancemame` that will look at all input devices. I have 3 images I built from scratch, 1 of the 3 images works where `advancemame` sees all the input devices. I can use my `uinput` and the keyboard at the sometime. I've compared config settings between the images and can't seem to find why one works and the others don't. I am wondering if it may be a security permission.

Also, is there a way to disable event0 and event1? I am not using `X11`, so `xinput` is not an option.

**EDIT**

Here are my input devices:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0d62 Product=0500 Version=0100
N: Name="2.4G Wireless Keyboard with Touchpad"
P: Phys=usb-bcm2708_usb-1.2/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=10000 7 ff9f207a c14057ff febeffdf ffefffff ffffffff fffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0d62 Product=0500 Version=0100
N: Name="2.4G Wireless Keyboard with Touchpad"
P: Phys=usb-bcm2708_usb-1.2/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.1/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd mouse0 event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=1f
B: KEY=4837fff 72ff32d bf544446 0 0 1f0001 20f90 8b17c000 677bfa d9415fed 9ed680 4400 0 10000002
B: REL=143
B: ABS=7f01 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=0001
N: Name="uinput-sample"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd mouse1 rfkill event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=100007
B: KEY=10000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff fffffffe
B: REL=3
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would be surprised if `advancedmame` haven't an option to use a given input device, and creating a symbolic link from `/proc/bus/input/` should be easy. That said, from the few I've read it support different input drivers, `event` support multiple keyboards, isn't this the driver you're using? [doc-advdev](http://advancemame.sourceforge.net/doc-advdev.html#3.1)

Comment: I agree that `advancemame` should have this option, but it wont recognizes the virtual keyboard if a "real" keyboard is plugged in. As for the `event`, how can I check?

Comment: I've downloaded sources of 1.2 is that your version? Not sure I'm looking in the right file (`keydrv.c`) but I see a function `log_std` used here and there `keyb: select driver %s`, do you have an `advancedmame` log or could you enable it? (could you add the content of `/proc/bus/input/handlers` when it work and when it doesn't?)

Comment: Please `/proc/bus/input/devices` too

Comment: @Alex its `event2` and version of `advancemame` is `0.106.1`

Comment: Are you using `udev` or something similar? There's a `/dev/input/by-id/` dir?

Comment: `/dev/input/by-id` shows all the physical keyboards, e.g. `usb-0d62_2.4G_Wireless_Keyboard_with_Touchpad-event-kbd` but not any virtual. Also, when I unplug the keyboard and check `/dev/input/by-id`, the directory does not exist

Comment: @Alex - Also I am using `udev`, so  maybe create a rule?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14493/discussion-between-alex-and-phil-vallone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the problem was running `advancemame` with `sudo` and not as a regular user `pi`, we didn't investigate why.

Comment: Thanks again. Good news is I did find the issue. If was a config setting in advmame. When run as sudo, it used the config file in `/root/.advance/advmame.rc`, when run as `pi` it used `/home/pi/.advance/advance.rc`. When I copied the .rc to the `/root/.advance` it worked. Like I said, thanks of the chat, it helped me trouble shoot the issue!

Comment: Glad it helped, have fun! :)